# MDX Query using DistinctCount, Except as a filter

Tags: optimization, ssas, distinct, mdx

I am new to MDX Querying and am trying to create a query that utilizes Except.  I currently have one that works when i do a filter with a bunch of OR's but it is very slow.

What i want to do is count the distinct back order lines (where that doesn't equal 0) except when 2 aging codes are set. (`050` and `060`).

This query seems to work but is extremely slow (not using except)

```
DISTINCTCOUNT(filter([Product].[Segment - Line - Types].[Product].members,  
  (([Measures].[BackOrderLineCount], [Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[005] ) OR  
  ([Measures].[BackOrderLineCount], [Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[010] )OR  
  ([Measures].[BackOrderLineCount], [Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[020] )OR 
  ([Measures].[BackOrderLineCount], [Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[030] )OR  
  ([Measures].[BackOrderLineCount], [Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[040] ))))
```

I was hoping if i switched it to "EXCEPT" it would speed it up...

Any help would be appreciated i've been searching all day for this.

Comment: I do not want aging codes of 050 and 060 so i meant to say "Not equal to..."

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use a `FILTER` function for this requirement.  Also, the minus operator is as good as `EXCEPT` while being more handy.
 You should be looking at obtaining tuples of products and aging code which have a value for back order line.

```
DISTINCTCOUNT([Product].[Segment - Line - Types].[Product].members * 
NonEmpty(
([Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].CHILDREN - {[Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[50], [Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[60]}), 
[Measures].[BackOrderLineCount])
)
```

The `NonEmpty` function returns those aging codes which **have** back order lines.

If you had to use `EXCEPT`, the code would look like below:

```
EXCEPT
(
[Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].CHILDREN,  {[Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[50], [Aging].[AgingCode].[Aging].&[60]}
)
```

Comment: Thanks Sourav_Agasti, I've tried the top 'DistinctCount" example and am getting a "The Syntax for ')' is incorrect."  So I'm looking to see why.  Also, do you have any webpages that maybe helpful for me as i learn MDX?

Comment: That was a typo. Edited my answer. If you are really serious about learning MDX, I would suggest you to set up Adventure works cube in your system. Then open up a new MDX query window and go through as many MDX functions as possible. Try googling "MDX function reference'. If you are a complete beginner, go through existing code and try to understand what it's doing. This way of practically learning the language will always beat trying to read through a hundred pages.

Comment: Give yourself a couple of months time and once you're a little comfortable with the language, try going through Chris Webb's blogs. Also try to go through and contribute to this site. It works wonders.